# How to populate dummy data into an existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table with given number of rows in which I'd like to replace personal informations with dummy data. I've written functions for this but actually struggling with how to implement it.

I'd like to do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable DROP COLUMN SomeName
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD COLUMN SomeName NVARCHAR(30) DEFAULT (SELECT * FROM dbo.FakeName)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just run an `UPDATE` on the column instead of dropping and readding it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dropping and adding a column, just do an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the actual data with dummy data , why can't you use update statement as below. We do almost similar in our day to day work. For ex. if we would like to sanitize actual email address of users while restoring the data in my local or test machine (in column SomeName) and in another column we just want to update it with 'XXX' .

```
    UPDATE SomeTable 
    SET Email_address= SUBSTRING(Email_address,0,CHARINDEX('@',Email_address)) + '@mytest.com',
    SomeName2= 'XXX',
```